# ¿Existe alguna diferencia en la funcionalidad de las variables var y let?

Tags: variables

Estoy empezando recién en el mundo de la programación, hasta el momento siempre he utilizado las variables let, quisiera saber si existe alguna funcionalidad diferente entre ambos tipos de variables y en que situaciones es recomendable usar cada una de ellas

Comment: Bienvenida. De qué lenguaje estás hablando?

Comment: Estoy hablando de JavaScript